# Step into code suddenly not working in Visual Studio code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

I have run into an issue where stepping into code (F11) while debugging is not working anymore. Step over works fine but not step into. This was all working fine and suddenly stopped working.
When I reach breakpoint and try stepping into the code only a .psm1 file opens in another tab and it does not step into the code.

Some things I've done, but was not successful:

- Uninstall and Reinstall VScode (to a previous version)
- Delete all bin files
- Disable all extensions
- Delete the solution's suo file

Visual Studio Code version is 1.71.2(User Setup)